# How to call a function written in VB from C# application

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a function written in vb

```
Public Function abc (ByVal x as Integer, ByVal y as String) As String 

End Function
```

I want to call this function on click of a button in C# applcation.

Comment: Just add the project reference

Comment: And what exactly are you having problems with? What are you stuck on?

Comment: I have added the reference of the dll, but not able to call this function.

Comment: is the vb function within a VB.NET dll? ..or is it in a VB6 dll?

Comment: For VB6, start reading about .NET interop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a reference to the assembly containing the code.
2. Create an object of the class containing the method (function) you want to
   call
3. Call the method `objectname.abc(3,"SomeSting");`

Comment: Hi,
My VB Dll name is MyDll. I have a module in this Module MyDll. And the function is written in this module. Now I wan to call this function from C# application.

Answer (score 2):

If your VB function is inside a module, you need to call it by specifying the module name.

```
string result = MyVbModule.abc(1, "Hello");
```

You may also need to specify the namespace, wich per default is the name of the VB project:

```
string result = MyDll.MyVbModule.abc(1, "Hello");
```

Comment: Hi, My VB Dll name is MyDll. I have a module in this Module MyDll. And the function is written in this module. Now I want to call this function from C# application. Should Module have any public specifier?

Comment: You will probably get a hint of what the structure is by the intellisense in the C# code if you just starts to write `MyDll.` and see what pops up.

Comment: Hi All,
Thanks for your support. I am able to call the function. What I did : I Created the Module as Public and then I added the reference of the vb dll. Then called the function like MyDll.MyDll.abc(1, "Hello").

Thank you all...

Comment: Hi, How were you able to do it? If the VB6 function is inside a module rather than a class module, then .NET intellisense does not even show it!

Answer (score 1):

Using this post I was able to just call a VB function inside a simple Class module. No VB.dll needed.

I needed to use some Date-math functions written in VB that where huge and almost impossible to rewrite. I had to make my comment an answer so it would fit and be easily understood.

**I made a VB Project inside my C# Solution next to the C# project.
I added a reference in the C# project to the VB one.**

I looked in Object Browser to see how it was referenced. 
Name of the Project was referenced, twice: "VB_Stuff.VB_Stuff".

In C# Razor Page I put a "**using VB_Stuff.VB_Stuff**" at the top.

In the Razor Page OnGetAsync where I needed the VB function(s) I declared an object with the name of the VB Class: **DateStuff obj = new DateStuff();**

Then I called the function (named fTest) with my Model's field . . .

```
DateStuff obj = new DateStuff();
Dances_Moderated.RecurYesNo =obj.fTest(Dances_Moderated.RecurYesNo.ToString());
```

I did this right before my Razor Page was going to load and display the Details Page for the "Dances_Moderated" Model.

**No .dlls! Just some VB code in a VB class in a VB Project inside a C# Solution.** 
Make sure you right click on the solution to add the project, otherwise from the File menu "New Project" it wants to add a new Solution no matter what you do.

Here is the simple VB Class file with the simple Test function.

```
Namespace VB_Stuff

    Public Class DateStuff

        Public Function fTest(ByVal Recurring As String) As String

            fTest = Recurring & "xxxxx"

        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```